# lapply returning numbers as list

Tags: r

I tried with below code to get a list of values. But it is returning numbers as shown below

```
lapply(c("a","b"), function(x){x = colDef(show =F)})
[[1]]
$show
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "colDef"

[[2]]
$show
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "colDef"
```

Expected output

```
$a
$show
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "colDef"

$b
$show
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "colDef"
```

Not sure what wrong I am doing here. Can anyone please help

Comment: You are passing an object without names. Try adding names: `lapply(setNames(c("a", "b"), c("a", "b")), colDef, show = FALSE)`. Also, you should define in your question where the `colDef` is from so your question is reproducible.